# Compile Error (tableofcontenents, maketitle)

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, titles

I'm trying to compile this file:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\author{Me}
\title{Test}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\tableofcontenents
\frontmatter
\section{Preface}
\section{Nomenclature}
\mainmatter
\section{Introduction}
\section{Result and discussion}
\subsection{Section}
\subsection{Another section}
\section{Conclusion}
\end{document}
```

But i get these two error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\maketitle ...ge \global \@topnum \z@ \@maketitle 
                                                  \fi \thispagestyle {titlep...
l.29 \maketitle

?

! Undefined control sequence.
l.30 \tableofcontenents

?
```

What could I do?
Thank you in advice!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't use the `doc` package here And the command is called `\tableofcontents`, not `\tableofcontenents`

Comment: What do you think `\usepackage{doc}` is for? If somebody recommended it to you, it's a good occasion for breaking a friendship. `;-)`

Comment: Thank you, now at least compile! The problem now is that the resulting .dvi has an empty Index and the sections are numbered as subsections.

Comment: For the index I found out I have to compile two or three times but the section problems still remain

Comment: @sworwitz: You always have to compile twice for the ToC(at least). Concerning the section numbers: I see section numbers as expected, but with a leading zero. You're not using any `\chapter` command in your document

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments (suggesting to remove the `doc` package from being included, correcting of typos and compiling twice)